# Function takes unusually long time to return

Tags: c

I am measuring how much time it takes to execute function compute_secret(). The pseudo code below is how I do my measurement.
The problem is that, there is a quite large different in between  `total_inside` (the time its take to execute the function body, measure inside the callee) vs.  `total_outside` (measure inside the caller). For example, `total_inside = 127ms`, `total_outside = 238ms`.

I understand that it takes sometime to call and return from function call. But it should not takes "that" long.

***So what are the common reasons when calling and returning from function cost too much time ?***

```
int encrypt(args){
    time start_inside = get_current_time();
    /**
         actually compute stuff
     **/
    time end_inside = get_current_time();
    time total_inside = end_inside - start_inside;
}

int main(){
    time start_outside = get_current_time();

    encrypt(args);

    time end_outside = get_current_time();
    time total_outside = end_outside - start_outside;
}
```

Comment: You are aware that **total_outside = total_inside + (whatever time taken to call and return)**

Comment: Yes, the problem is **(whatever time taken to call and return)** seems unusually long (as large as total_inside), so I wonder what could be the reasons ?. For example, if **total_inside  = 127ms**, then **(whatever time taken to call and return) = 116ms**

Comment: You don’t show how you print the elapsed time inside the function. Nevertheless, it is unlikely that the formatting and printing takes 111 ms.

Comment: Check the start of the inside interval relative to the outside interval. Does the time discrepancy persist when executing encrypt multiple times in a row during a program run ?

Comment: Actually, this is not **(whatever time taken to call and return)** but **(whatever time taken to call and return)+(whatever time spent on system/runtime ancillary activities, possibly scheduling other processes)**.

Comment: In my understanding total_outside time is the sum of total_inside time,time taken for computing start_inside time and whatever time taken to call and return encrypt function.

Comment: What is `get_current_time()`? and `time` type? How are you printing `time` type? Also the function name `encrypt` is already taken by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/encrypt.html).

Comment: A C function never takes 111ms to return unless you have a poor CPU that is saturated by other processes. My guess is that your problem is in the time calculation and printing, could you elaborate on this point ?

Comment: @mouviciel, it depends what kind of time measurement tool he took, by example the clock function works with the process time and does not count other processes CPU time. But it's still an approximation only.

Answer (score 0):

From a glance at the psudo-code, I see a number of things:

- the first is that it's pseudo-code, which rather hampers our ability to do a full analysis :-) So comments below are based on what I see as most likely options.
- you haven't actually posted the code for `get_current_time()`, the execution time of that may be irrelevant but that's not *necessarily* the case. Sometimes timing functions get in the way of accuarte timing.
- the reason I mention that last point is that the outer time calculation will consist of the function calculations itself, the stack setup and teardown, *and the inner time calculation.* You should probably just run with the outer time to see if the timings are reduced.
- because of the vagaries of code execution, it's often better to time something in a loop and average the time taken. For all we know, the first call may take 250ms and subsequent calls take 1ms.

If you're really concerned about stack setup and teardown (it's usually not *too* bad but it's definitely not free and, for very short-lived functions, it can often swamp the execution time of the actual work being done), there are options.

For example, you can choose higher optimisation levels, or force your function inline such as by making it a function macro, assuming you protect against all the usual macro-related issues, of course.

Comment: another possible problem is optimization reordering the timing calls; timing is not observable behaviour

Comment: @M.M, I assume you mean *within* the timing function, yes. From memory, a full expression (eg, each line in `main` since they're terminated with `;`) is a sequence point, so no re-oredering is possible at that level.

Comment: This is about the as-if rule, not sequence points. The compiler only has to produce the same observable behaviour as the abstract machine,and timing results are not observable behaviour